# How to view Docker Application in the Browser

Tags: docker

I have run the following command to have a Docker application (ASP.NET Core) run on Windows desktop:
`docker run --name eshopweb --rm -it -p 8000:5106 web`

The console outputs the following:

```
Hosting environmnet: Production
Context root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

When visiting the following URL, localhost refused to connect.
`http://localhost:5106/`

How can a Docker application be viewed in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

According to the output, the application is listening on 80;

You need to expose the port 80 of your container.

Do something like:

```
docker run -dit -p 8000:5106 -p 10080:80 --name eshopweb web
```

And then try: http://localhost:10080

Answer (score 0):

8000 is your external port while 5106 is internal port of the container. Try http://localhost:8000/